# Create a contiguous dynamic matrix

Tags: c++, c++17

Arrays have this nice property of being contiguous blocks of memory. When using `new` to allocate memory for an array, it returns a pointer to a **contiguous** block of memory. However, if I allocate a matrix using `new`, like this:

```
#include <iostream> //std::cin

int main()
{
    int n, m;
    std::cin >> n >> m;
    int** mat = new int*[n];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        mat[i] = new int[m];
    //use the matrix in some way
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        delete[] mat[i];
    delete[] mat;
    return 0;
}
```

This works, but `mat` doesn't point to a contiguous block of size `n * m * sizeof(int)`. How can I do this in C++? I am just complying to the latest standard (that is C++17) and nothing else. I want an answer that doesn't involve STL containers or external libraries.

Please don't answer about C, as that is pretty easy to do in both C99 and C11 using variable-length arrays:

```
#include <stdio.h> //scanf
#include <stdlib.h> //malloc, free

int main()
{
    int n, m;
    scanf("%d %d", &n, &m);
    //int mat[n][m]; VLA, but I want dynamic
    int (*mat)[m] = malloc(n * sizeof *mat);
    //use the matrix in some way;
    free(mat);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: To begin with, don't do dynamic allocation yourself and instead use `std::vector`. As for your problem, you could create a vector of `n * m` elements, and use arithmetic to access each element in the matrix.

Comment: I didn't ask if I should allocate it myself, I just asked how can I do it. Allocating memory yourself, while dangerous, can be vey efficient as opposed to using STL containers like `std::vector` which reallocate themselves whenever they want.

Comment: Or, even better, use some library that implements this functionality for you, such as [eigen](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/group__TopicStorageOrders.html).

Comment: @DarkAtom Vectors don't reallocate _whenever they want_. If `m` and `n` is fixed and you create a vector of `m*n` elements, there is no reason for further reallocation, unless you ask for it.

Comment: A vector object is a bit larger than a simple array. For example it stores the size of the array. It stores the allocator object etc.

Comment: @DarkAtom Then, use a `std::unique_ptr<int[]>` instead of `std::vector<int>`. It has no memory overhead.

Comment: If you do e.g. `std::vector<int> mat(n * m);` then you create a vector of exactly `n * m` elements. As long as you don't `push_back` or `insert` new elements, there won't be any more allocations. And efficiency wise, using the vectors `operator[]` function is trivial and any overhead after possible compiler optimizations won't even be measureable. Don't dismiss the standard containers, the standard algorithms or the compilers capability of optimizations.

Comment: And if `n * m` is more than a few elements, the "overhead" of storing the size in the vector will be dwarfed by the data itself. And it has the added pro that you don't need to keep track of the size yourself (which of course *also* will take us space). And perhaps it's time to edit your question to ask about your *real* problem instead of asking for help with a solution to an unknown problem? And what are your requirements? And why are you so focused on saving four to eight bytes of memory?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude the question is how to allocate a matrix, not create a matrix from STL containers. I am not arguing that STL is not good, I am just trying to learn how to do it myself and not just be like "Oh the STL can do it for me".

Comment: Lastly, first of all write *good* and *readable* and *maintainable* and *working* code. Manual optimizations tend to create bad code. Once you have a good and working base, you *measure* and *benchmark* and *profile* (the compiler-optimized program) to find the very worst bottlenecks, and if those aren't "good enough" (which often *is* good enough) then concentrate on those *only*. And write plenty of documentation and comments about the code you manually optimize.

Comment: If you want to do it using plain pointers, smart or not, for curiosity and as a learning experience, it would help if you said so. Because unless you have other extremely special requirements (that you need to tell us) the solution to all "dynamic array" questions will be "use vector". Or, depending on actual problem and use-case, "use library X" (which guessing from the name `mat` would either be OpenCV or Eigen or similar).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude This is a very basic example. I don't know why you are treating it like the source code for some big project. Of course in real code I would use STL

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude ok, my bad, I should have said it is a learning experience and not real code. I will do that next time. Sorry

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's what you were doing, almost exactly the same but without the non-contiguous memory:

```
#include <iostream> //std::cin
#include <memory>

int main()
{
    int n, m;
    std::cin >> n >> m;
    auto matrix_data = std::make_unique<int[]>(n * m);
    auto mat = std::make_unique<int[]>(n);
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) { mat[i] = matrix_data.get() + i * m; }

    // Use the matrix in some way

    // No need to free anything - we're using smart pointers.

    // No need to return 0 from main - that's the default
}
```

Notes:

1. This is still ugly code... you'd likely better create a proper matrix class, or better still - use somebody else's implementation.
2. It is better to follow @Someprogrammerdude's suggestion and use arithmetic rather than an array of pointers.

Comment: Yes, of course I am going to implement a class for this, but I was asking for the implementation.

Comment: By the way, some compilers don't auto-return 0 from main.

Comment: @DarkAtom: 1. Compilers which don't return 0 from main are non-standard-complaint. 2. I wouldn't use this implementation. But for Someprogrammerdude's approach you would _have_ to write a class - for the `operator[]`.

Comment: @DarkAtom They [must](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.start.main#5.sentence-2) since C++11 if you omit the `return` statement (if they don't, they have a bug). You tagged your question with C++17.

Answer (score 1):

I kind of still don't know what particularly are you asking for. To store matrix elements in a contiguous location, simply allocate the memory for them as a one-dimensional dynamic array. The two basic options have been already discussed, either use a vector:

```
std::vector<int> mat(m * n);
```

or, if its memory overhead is significant for you, use a unique pointer:

```
auto mat = std::make_unique<int[]>(m * n);
```

Then, to access an element with `i` row index and `j` column index, simply use:

```
a_i_j = mat[i * n + j];
```

assuming `m` is the number of rows and `n` is the number of columns. This formula stores elements in so-called *row-major* order. If you need the *column-major* order, switch to:

```
a_i_j = mat[j * m + i];
```

Of course, whole approach would be much better encapsulated in a class with some getter operator `mat(i, j);`.

Comment: This is the same as `int* mat = new int[m * n]`, just using smart pointers.

Comment: @DarkAtom Yes, it is. And it is what you want, isn't it?

Comment: @DarkAtom The whole idea is very simply, i.e., to put all matrix rows (or columns) next to each other in memory in a 1-D array.

Comment: if it was that easy I wouldn't ask this question. Take a look at my C example. I am allocating an n * m array and assigning it to a pointer whose underlying type's size is actually `m * sizeof(int)`. So that means I can access it as mat[i][j] and not need to bother with mat[i * n + m].

Comment: @DarkAtom So, the only point of your question is how to access elements with `mat[i][j]` instead of `mat(i,j)`? Then, the answer is that there is no language-provided option to enable `mat[i][j]` for a dynamic 2-D array with contiguous storage. However, you can use the solution provided by einpoklum with an additional array. Then, you can write `mat[i][j]` at a price of this array storage.

Comment: @DarkAtom I didn't understand your problem, since you didn't upvote einpoklum's answer and accept it. Why?

Comment: That's explains it :). Anyway, I still think it's much better to encapsulate all this stuff with a class. An obvious advantage of encapsulation is that you can support both _row-major_ and _column-major_ element ordering (any built-in way would use only a single one). Moreover, you can even use other orderings, such as the _Morton_ (z-curve) ordering, which is, in some cases, preferable for matrix processing. With one major class and some helper one, you may even make your implementation to support the `mat[i][j]` syntax.

Comment: @DarkAtom Another problem is, that if you just allocate with `new` (same holds for vectors and unique pointers), your matrix elements might not be aligned enough for SIMD processing. Within a class, you can easily solve this by using a proper alignment-aware allocation function, such as `posix_memalign`, or `std::aligned_alloc` from C++17.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a 2D matrix class that enables `m[i][j]` support and has a contiguous storage. It contains a minimalistic set of member functions to create and access elements.
It's a shame that the STD library does not provide such functionality. `[i][j]` element access is way less error prone than index arithmetics.

```
#include <cstddef>
#include <vector>

template <typename T>
class matrix
{
public:
    using value_type = T;

private:
    class row_view
    {
    public:
        constexpr row_view(size_t length, value_type *begin)
            : _length(length),
            _begin(begin)
        {}

        value_type &operator[](size_t i) {
            // TODO: check bounds
            return *std::next(_begin, i);
        }

        const value_type &operator[](size_t i) const {
            // TODO: check bounds
            return *std::next(_begin, i);
        }

        size_t size() const {
            return _length;
        }
    private:
        size_t _length;
        value_type *_begin;
    };
public:

    matrix(size_t rows, size_t cols, value_type &&defaultVal)
        : _rows(rows),
        _array(rows * cols, std::move(defaultVal))
    {}

    matrix(size_t rows, size_t cols)
        : matrix(rows, cols, value_type{})
    {}

    size_t rows() const noexcept {
        return _rows;
    }

    size_t cols() const noexcept {
        return _array.size() / _rows;
    }

    auto operator[](size_t rowIndex) -> row_view{
        const size_t offset = cols() * rowIndex;
        return {cols(), &_array[offset]};
    }

    auto operator[](size_t rowIndex) const -> const row_view{
        const size_t offset = cols() * rowIndex;
        return {cols(), &_array[offset]};
    }

private:
    size_t _rows;
    std::vector<value_type> _array;
};
```

https://godbolt.org/z/qoG6jGbh5